# Referencing a Class in a different Class

Tags: java, class

In my class B, I want to be able to use methods from my class A.  This is what I have tried.

1. Imported class A
2. initialized it - classA a = new classA(null, null);
3. The added to my methods where I want to use a class A method

   public void getAMethod() {
       a.getTestValue;
    }

My questions are:

1. Is this the correct way to do it?
2. Is every time I execute class B, is it always creating a new instance of class A?
3. If class A is opened and I run class B, does class B get the current values of variables in class A, or does it get the class A defaults because of new classA(null, null)?

My issues are:

1. I am getting 2 different values for the same variable.

Example: Class A -

```
initialize = boolean test = false
```

When class A dialog opens , set test = true

Create method

```
public boolean getTestValue() {
   return test;
}
```

From within class A when I run getTestValue, it is always true
From class B when getTestValue is called, it always returns false (even with the class A dialog open)

It seems like that class b is making a new instance of class A every time, so it only sees the default values of class A.  When class B calls class A, I need to get the current values of class A, not the defaults

***EDIT***
I changed the method in Class A to static and it fixed the issue I was having.  This was a big help to me - Thanks to all for the suggestions!

Comment: Absolutely not clear what you are asking. It would help if the 

"3.The added to my methods where I want to use a class A method

public void getAMethod() { a.getTestValue; }"

part would show a self-containing source code fragment.

Comment: Do you think you could post more substantial code for your two classes and how you are calling these methods?

Comment: I agree with previous two comments, I really don't understand the question. What do you mean by "executing a class" creating an instance of that class by calling new, or calling a method of that class? If you want to see if A gets instantiated twice just add some println to the constructor of A. I would also like to suggest you books Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel and Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there's a fair amount of ground to cover, but I'll try to be brief and answer each question in turn.

**1. Is this the correct way to do it?**

You don't *typically* need to import classes in a small program. If `ClassA` and `ClassB` are inside the same *package*, or they both do not have a package assigned, but reside in the same directory, then no importing is required.

As far as wrapping `ClassA` methods in `ClassB` methods, no, *no*. You can access a `ClassA` *static* method from within `ClassB` at any time by doing;

```
ClassA.myMethodInClassA();
```

If `myMethodInClassA();` is *not* static, then you need to call it on an **instance** of `ClassA` so, (still in ClassB) you would do;

```
ClassA myA = new ClassA();
myA.myMethodInClassA();
```

Which brings me on to `static` vs `non static` fields. If your fields `initialize` and `test` are marked as `static`, such as;

```
public static boolean initialize = false;
```

Then they will *always* have the same value across *all* instances of `ClassA` and can be access from anywhere with;

```
if(ClassA.initialize) {
    //something
}
```

If they are *not* marked as static, then again (much like the non-static methods) you need an **instance** of `ClassA` with which to query the fields such as;

```
ClassA myA = new ClassA();
if(myA.initialize) {
    //something
}
```

And in this case, each **instance** of `ClassA` has its own copy of `initialize`, so the value of `initialize` depends on which instance you are querying.

**2. Is every time I execute class B, is it always creating a new instance of class A?**

If you call a constructor for `ClassA` inside the constructor for `ClassB` then the answer is yes, in other words if you do;

```
public ClassB() {
    //constructor for ClassB
    ClassA c = new ClassA();
}
```

Then yes, you will create a new `ClassA` *every* time you create a new `ClassB`.

**3. If class A is opened and I run class B, does class B get the current values of variables in class A, or does it get the class A defaults because of new classA(null, null)?**

If by 'opened' you mean you ran `java ClassA` and then ran `java ClassB` in your command prompt, then what you have there is two separate programs, two instances of the JVM running in parallel. These two programs have nothing to do with one another, and cannot communicate with each other in **any** way unless you specifically implement something.

If by 'opened' you mean constructed, such as `new ClassA();` then we're talking about class vs instance members again.

I ranted on about `static` vs `non-static` fields and methods in my answer to question 1, which covers this ground. Overall I would advise you to read some docs, such as:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

**TLDR: Go read this link ^^**

Answer (score 1):

@Jkteater As u did not support your question with Code snippet but as per your question

```
Is this the correct way to do it ?
```

Ans:you can use  method of class A in any other class via two method one is my making the object of class A in class B (classA a=new classA(); A.getTestValue();)and second is by inheritance by extending class A into class B(class B extends class A).

```
Is every time I execute class B, is it always creating a new instance of class A?
```

Ans:If u dont want to create a new instance of class A then either extend class A in class B or make your method static in class A.In static case you will use it through class name only (A.getTestValue();)

```
If class A is opened and I run class B, does class B get the current
  values of variables in class A, or does it get the class A defaults
   because of new classA(null, null)
```

Ans:classA a=new classA(null,null);this class(null,null) is a constructor which is used to initialize non static data member of class A wont make any difference what is the current value of class B,the value u will pass through this constructor this will initialize the non static data member of class A.

For your below question can u please paste the exact code so that i can able to give to the exact answer..

Answer (score 0):

make variable test as static, since you are creating a new instance of A, the values are different

Is this the correct way to do it? 
well that depends on detailed use case
Is every time I execute class B, is it always creating a new instance of class A?
yes, every time you create instance of B, it will create a new instance of A
If class A is opened and I run class B, does class B get the current values of variables in class A, or does it get the class A defaults because of new classA(null, null)?
since you are creating a new instance, you will get default values